# ASP.NET MVC 4 RC unobstrusive javascript validation on default login form does not show error messages

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I created ASP.NET MVC 4 Beta internet application, ran it, brought up login form, pressed "Login" without entering anything in user name or password. I get validation messages alongside login and password text boxes.

I installed ASP.NET MVC 4 RC, did the same steps, error messages don't show up. The text boxes have red borders indicating something's wrong but no error messages.

I'm using VS 2010 SP1.

Can somebody please help me understand what has changed from beta to rc and how to fix this?

Thanks.